# Jenkins build with differents maven repository

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have an  Jenkins build machine with the follow situation:

```
 1. MY_MAVEN_PROJECT
 2. MY_MAVEN_PROJECT_BRANCH_1.0
 3. MY_MAVEN_PROJECT_ nightly_build
```

All of these task use a common maven repository located in **~/m2./repository**

The problem is that the all builds use the same maven repository, 
when I execute the nightly build  I’d like to remove also the maven repository, in order to have a very clean situation.

So I was wondering if it is possible to have an situation like this:

```
 1. MY_MAVEN_PROJECT
   |_ workspace maven repository (workspace/MY_MAVEN_PROJECT/m2./repository)


 2. MY_MAVEN_PROJECT_BRANCH_1.0
    |_ workspace maven repository (workspace/ MY_MAVEN_PROJECT_BRANCH_1.0/ m2./repository)


 3.MY_MAVEN_PROJECT_ nightly_build
   |_ workspace maven repository(workspace/MY_MAVEN_PROJECT_ nightly_build/m2./repository)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins > maven build step > advanced settings, there is a checkbox that says "Use private Maven repository".
When this option is checked, Jenkins will tell Maven to use $WORKSPACE/.repository as the local Maven repository. This means each job will get its own isolated Maven repository just for itself.